# Process and threads in android

Tags: android, multithreading

Can service and activity run in same linux process at the same time.?

```
private class Test extends  Service{
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Computational logic

        }
    }).start();


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Does the the thread execute in new linux process or the same process which call this service(UI process)?.

Answer (score 1):

By default every application runs in its own process and all components of the application run in that process.

> Can service and activity run in same linux process at the same time.?

The above statement already answer this question, and here's what Services  [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) one more time says:

> The Service object itself does not imply it is running in its own
>   process; unless otherwise specified, it runs in the same process as
>   the application it is part of.

For further reading consider this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

`A Service is not a separate process. The Service object itself does not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part of.`

`A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).`

Unless you mention in manifest, the service will run in the same thread: See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html